# Reset choices js dropdown select

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dropdown

I have dropdown from [choices.js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices) library in my MVC project in .cshtml file that is defined like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="institutions" onclick="getFilter()">
    @Html.DropDownList("organizationFilterId", 
    null, 
    @Web.Localization.LocalizationResources.All, 
    new { @id = "OrganizationFilterDDL", 
    @class = "form-select js-choice" 
    })
</div>
```

I want on click of resetFIlters to reset this dropdown to default value that is set before option on dropdown is chosen.

I tried many different options in javascript but non of them seems to be working:

```
var organizationFilterDDL = document.getElementById('OrganizationFilterDDL');
1. organizationFilterDDL.selectedIndex = 0;
2. organizationFilterDDL.selectedIndex = -1;
3. organizationFilterDDL.value = '';
4.  $('#OrganizationFilterDDL').prop('selected', function () {
            return this.defaultSelected;
    });
```

Library methods defined in [documentation](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices) not working also:

```
const choices = new Choices(document.getElementById('OrganizationFilterDDL'));
//setChoiceByValue method
5. choices.setChoiceByValue("");

//clearStore() method
6. choices.clearStore();
```

When I try to console.log organizationFilterDDL and choices this i got this:

[image]

If I try to add click event to this remove button it doesn't reset and just reopens dropdown:
[image]

Any ideas?